# How can I find an element I can't see so I can position it correctly?

Tags: css-position, absolute

I've got an element it's `position: absolute`, and `left:0;`

As soon as I put in `top:0;` it disappears.  I know it's there somewhere but I can't work out where.  I tried increasing top by 10px at a time and decreasing by -10px at a time but it doesn't show up.

Is there any way I can see where it is positioned on the page easily so I can work out what I am doing wrong and bring it into view?

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue that you are facing.

Comment: I don't know how to do that.  When I give something position absolute, it disappears off the screen.

Comment: Add the code which you are facing issues with in the question, so that others would be able to reproduce the issue and provide answers accordingly.

Comment: I guess I just didn't know which nodes to include from the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why `left: 0;` worked and `top: 0;` caused a problem but I added `position: relative;` to the parent which allowed me to see my element and position it.